# Trying to make a program that separates an amount in to coins

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that takes an input amount and separates them into how many coins it would equal. So far what i wrote gives me the right amount most of the time but sometimes it will be a penny off and i don't know why.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double amount;
    System.out.println("This program will display the number of "
            + "quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies based on the "
            + "amount you enter below.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Please enter an amount: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    amount = scan.nextDouble();

    double quarter = amount/0.25;
    amount = amount % 0.25;
    double dime = amount/0.10;
    amount = amount % 0.10;
    double nickel = amount/0.05;
    amount = amount % 0.05;
    double penny = amount/0.01;


    System.out.println("Quarters: " + (int)quarter);
    System.out.println("Dimes " + (int)dime);
    System.out.println("Nickels " + (int)nickel);
    System.out.println("Pennies " + (int)penny);
```

When i input 2.47, i get:

```
Please enter an amount: 2.47
Quarters: 9
Dimes: 2
Nickels: 0
Pennies: 2
```

But when i input 1.47, i get:

```
Please enter an amount: 1.47

Quarters: 5
Dimes: 2
Nickels: 0
Pennies: 1
```

Comment: If you take a look [here](https://ideone.com/OHhyCJ), you'll see it's actually 1.99...62, because of inaccurate floating point arithmetic. When you cast to integer, decimal places are completely truncated.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for your problem is that floating point arithmetic is subject to rounding errors.   At a certain point, one of the intermediate floating point results is not completely accurate, and the error is *amplified* when you use a cast to convert the `double` to an `int`.

For a full explanation of why this sort of thing happens, read the answers to [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Solution You should recode this using the `int` (or `long`) type to represent a whole number of cents.

Start with this:

```
long amount = (long) (100 * scan.nextDouble());
```

and then recode the rest of the method accordingly.

Comment: If it's a duplicate of an existing question, please CV as such :). Comment other details if necessary.